# Collective noun for equalities and inequalities?

Tags: proof-writing, terminology

Is there a collective noun for equalities and inequalities?

For example, say I'm writing a proof:

---

According to *Theorem 17.7* the vector $\beta$ satisfies the following
**equalities and inequalities**:
\begin{align}
    \beta(S) &\ge v(S), \quad \forall S \subseteq N\\
    \beta &= \gamma \\
    \beta &\in A
\end{align}

---

Is there one specific word I can use instead of the phrase "equalities and inequalities" that will succinctly convey my intention?

Note also that the logic statement $\beta \in A$ is neither an equality nor an inequality, so my description in the example above isn't even accurate despite being exhaustive

Comment: Just remove 'equalities and inequalities' entirely. Alternatively, you could say 'relations'

Comment: Feels like in this context you could just say "properties," or if you insist on referring to equality "(in)equalities." I don't know of a collective noun for the pair, but considering we're talking about saving two words for what seems like no reason other than to do so, I don't see a point in trying to bother either.

Comment: You could use "relations", I guess.

Comment: @Jakobian In this example my intentions are clear without the phrase, but the example here is merely an illustration. I still need a word I can use in other cases where more explicit phrasing is required

Comment: @EeveeTrainer as well, see above; this example is merely for illustration purposes.

Comment: Or "conditions".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commenters above have noted, the word "relations" seems suitable for this purpose.

I'll mark this as the accepted answer unless additional suggestions are submitted